# jfreechart-1.0.14-swt.jar maven dependency using system path

Tags: maven-2

I need to add maven dependency in my POM file for jfreechart-1.0.14-swt.jar. I have used below dependency in xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart-swt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jfreechart-1.0.14-swt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

even tried with this one:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart-swt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

But in both cases the build is failing. Can anyone let me know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above issue is resolved now.. did some R&D

correct pom dependency is:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart-swt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jfreechart-swt-1.0.14.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```